# Иногда вместо иконок отображаются unicode символы

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, frontend, шрифты, иконки

При исспользовании своего шрифта для отображения иконок иногда в браузере google chrome наблюдается не корректное отображение иконок.
**(Повторюсь это происходит не всегда)**

Шрифты загружаются всегда.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

[image: Пример иконки]
[image: Пример иконки]

Comment: Может быть шрифт просто не успевает подгрузится? Шрифт вызывается через путь "http(s)://..." или что-то вроде "../myFont.ttf"? Если первое и шрифт лежит на том же сервере, стоит попробовать локальный путь.

Comment: @Eleferen

Шрифт лежит на сервере вместе с остальными файлами. 


путь выглядит как `url('/fonts/font-my-icons/icons.woff2') format('woff2')`